# Play music from iPhone on MacBook using iPhone 4 dock?

Tags: iphone

We have an iPhone 4 dock (the official apple one, and not the universal one) which I noticed has a headphone connection on the back. Is it possible to connect that to a Macbook (Pro) and play music from the iPhone through the laptop speakers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's theoretically possible to take the sound output from the iPhone dock and run it through a 3.5" cable into the input jack in the computer, it's much easier (and better quality) to simply [fire up iTunes 10 and play the media through the computer directly](https://superuser.com/questions/9794/play-music-on-iphone-through-computer/184024#184024).

Comment: +1 Cool - I didn't realise they'd changed this in iTunes 10. You certainly didn't used to be able to do it in older versions (I've tried before and wondered why they'd be so brain-dead as to prevent you from doing it). Thanks!